# Force skipping DBT models if source is not fresh

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

As the title says, I'm looking for a way on how to force skip a model if one of my sources is not updated/fresh using the dbt freshness. Our current setup is as follows:

We basically have models that are sourcing from different snowflake tables and we materialize them as a table. The sources have different freshness frequency and if one of the sources for the model is not updated, we want it to skip that model from computing/calculating since it will just return the same data.

We have tried using if/else in the model itself using Jinja and just run "SELECT * FROM {{this}}" to recreate the table using the old data but it is very hacky and doesn't really skip the model.

So we are looking for better ways on how to leverage the result of DBT freshness command to determine if the models should run or just be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running v1.1 or newer and don't mind an experimental API, you can use the `source_status` selector to only refresh models downstream from sources that have received new data. From the [docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/methods#the-source_status-method):

> Another element of job state is the source_status of a prior dbt invocation. After executing dbt source freshness, for example, dbt creates the sources.json artifact which contains execution times and max_loaded_at dates for dbt sources.

That means your script that runs dbt in production needs to invoke dbt twice, with the first invocation saving the state of the sources. Again, from the docs:

```bash
# You can also set the DBT_ARTIFACT_STATE_PATH environment variable instead of the --state flag.
$ dbt source freshness # must be run again to compare current to previous state
$ dbt build --select source_status:fresher+ --state path/to/prod/artifacts
```

If you want to do the *opposite*, and exclude models downstream from sources that haven't updated, you can use the `--exclude` flag instead:

```bash
# You can also set the DBT_ARTIFACT_STATE_PATH environment variable instead of the --state flag.
$ dbt source freshness # must be run again to compare current to previous state
$ dbt build --exclude source_status:error+ --state path/to/prod/artifacts
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this! when you say invoke dbt twice, do you mean run "dbt source freshness" twice before running the dbt build? also, i've been reading the docs for this method and having trouble understanding the path/to/prod/artifacts, is this the path where the state was stored?